# Graphical freezes and live CD boot failures

Tags: 14.04, ati, xubuntu, kubuntu, freeze

I experience regular short graphics freezes (mouse stops moving, words typed in are finished later) and at times the system freezes completely. This issue is so nasty that it makes the system unusable. This error already occurs in all live distributions, making it impossible to install the OS. The only installation attempt that succeeded was Xubuntu 14.04 (i386), but now the same problems appear when I use the system on my hard disk.

All live distributions will run perfectly when executed in Virtualbox on my Windows 7 system, which also works beautifully.

I have tried the following flavours of Ubuntu 14.04:

Kubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit - I don't get past the first screen which lets me choose between trying Kubuntu or installing it - when selecting either option the screen goes black and reports a CPU error.

Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 64-bit - frequent mouse freezes and ultimate system crash on live CD

Xubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit - frequent mouse freezes on live CD, installation crashes

Xubuntu 14.04 i386 - mouse freezes on live CD and in my installation; this is the only version where the hard disk install succeeded.

The live distributions of Linux that I have used before (Knoppix 7.2 and gparted 0.4.6.1) run perfectly. However, Linux Mint 17 shows the same mouse freeze / system crash problems. You can see I've tried a lot of distributions unsuccessfully.

My system is an Acer Aspire 7750G notebook, Intel Core i5 2430M with 2.4 GHz min., AMD Radeon HD 6650M / Intel switchable graphics with 2 GB VRAM, 8 GB memory.
My BIOS version is up to date.

Is this a known issue or a bug worth reporting? How can I get at least my Xubuntu version to run?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I've removed the "boot" tag and added "ATI" as this looks like an AMD/ATI driver problem.  Unfortunately I don't have an ATI Radeon so won't be able to help you any further. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Probably some sort of hardware incompatibility with some versions/distros. You could try searching for your exact laptop & someone else might already know what will work for it, but I think it might be a boot option...

Tried some boot options that might help? The live iso has some listed under it's F6 "Other Options" menu. Like nomodeset, noacpi, noapic, nolapic, etc...?

See this Ubuntu help page for more info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

[image]