# freezing/hanging at startup/login

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, screen, mode

My Ubuntu 14.04.1 setup freezes while I am on the internet, and now it won't start anymore. I get a black screen after login and I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

When I run the recovery mode it gets stuck at random parts, all related to USB, for example:

```
[4.966044] usbscore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[5.175943] hid-generic 0003 USB HID - Usb Keyboard
```

Each time I try, it gets stuck at a different point, but it never starts correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the login messages generally show a line when something finishes loading, so it *could* be freezing/pausing on a different item. If you think it's a USB item, a quick test would be to unplug every USB device (hubs too) and see if it works then (If you have a non-usb keyboard that would be a plus).

And sometimes (often?) boot issues can be fixed by trying a "boot option" (or "kernel (boot) option), like `nomodeset`, `noacpi`, `noapic`, `nolapic`, etc...? The live iso has some listed under it's F6 "Other Options" menu.

See this Ubuntu help page for more info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

[image]
([From another answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565947/graphical-freezes-and-live-cd-boot-failures/566088#566088))

**But**, in your case, since you said *"freezes while I am on the internet, and now it won't start anymore"* I'm suspecting it may be the WiFi adapter (or maybe it's config) that's gone bad. If you boot from a live ISO of 14.04.1 (or 14.04, or any) does it work then? And/or if you unplug the WiFi adapter does it work then?