# cannot install ubuntu 12.04 LTS using bootable pendrive

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS -64bit ISO file and created bootable pendrive using Startup Disk Creator.

Using this pen drive,when i try with "install Ubuntu" or "Try ubuntu without Installing" installation stops at ubuntu pink screen background.

I already have 12.04 LTS -64 bit and 32 bit in my laptop,Am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS -64bit in new partition.

I have tried this pen drive with different desktop/laptop and it works fine with "install Ubuntu" or "Try ubuntu without Installing" so i don't have any doubt with my bootable pen drive.

please suggest me how can i overcome with this issue.

Regards
Senthil

Comment: Your image link seems to be broken, please check and edit it. Thank you!

Comment: The requested page "/sites/de...?itok=9AT2L2e9&destination=sites/de..." could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly incompatible graphics, or some other setting. Tried some boot options that might help? The live iso has some listed under it's F6 "Other Options" menu. Like `nomodeset`, `noacpi`, `noapic`, `nolapic`, etc...?

See this Ubuntu help page for more info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

[image]

[similar to [Graphical freezes and live CD boot failures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565947/graphical-freezes-and-live-cd-boot-failures/566088#566088) ]

Comment: The installation setup is not showing any options (f1, f2.. f6 etc). 
I have removed the quiet splash and added "nomodeset" in the grub.cfg.

with this, installation sucks after the line 

"Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done"

please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Use the "Try without installing" and then try other options until you can boot successfully, and/or search (google, duckduckgo, yahoo, etc) for your exact computer and see if anyone else knows how to make it boot Ubuntu?